# Removing and replacing the middle part of a string in bash

Tags: bash, string

I've a few strings:

```
Central and Western</td><td><a href="javascript:pop1('major-housing-estate/30006.html');" title="Kwun Lung Lau">Kwun Lung Lau

Central and Western</td><td><a href="javascript:pop1('major-housing-estate/61782.html');" title="The Merton">The Merton

Eastern</td><td><a href="javascript:pop1('major-housing-estate/10038.html');" title="Fung Wah Estate">Fung Wah Estate

Wong Tai Sin</td><td><a href="javascript:pop1('major-housing-estate/20134.html');" title="Tsz Oi Court">Tsz Oi Court
```

And I want to remove and replace the middle parts:

From:

```
</td><td><a href="javascript:
```

To:

```
">
```

I want to replace this entire part with the character:

```
;
```

I need my strings to become:

```
Central and Western;Kwun Lung Lau

Central and Western;The Merton

Eastern;Fung Wah Estate

Wong Tai Sin;Tsz Oi Court
```

How do I do this in a generic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings are in a file called `file`:

```
$ sed 's|</td><td><a href="javascript:[^>]*">|;|g' file
Central and Western;Kwun Lung Lau
Central and Western;The Merton
Eastern;Fung Wah Estate
Wong Tai Sin;Tsz Oi Court
```

If your string is in a shell variable called `s`:

```
$ echo "$s"
Central and Western</td><td><a href="javascript:pop1('major-housing-estate/30006.html');" title="Kwun Lung Lau">Kwun Lung Lau
$ echo "$s" | sed 's|</td><td><a href="javascript:[^>]*">|;|g'
Central and Western;Kwun Lung Lau
```